# Difference between gethostname() and [NSProcessInfo hostName]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, hostname

So, I have an iPhone app that freezes at startup with one particular iPhone on a mobile carrier.

I traced this down to a `[NSProcessInfo hostName]` call which blocks for around 45 seconds before returning what I think is a correct result. I don't really see a particular reason for why it should block, but it definitely appears to be making a network call for each call.

I tried replacing this though with something which appears to do the exact same thing, but without taking any amount of time, `gethostname()`.

In the end, they both return the exact same thing in all cases I could come up with. What exactly is the difference and why is `[NSProcessInfo hostName]` so slow?

Comment: Not sure whether it is relevant, but some cues seem to be here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16902907/3125367

Comment: Well `gethostbyname()` is used to get host information of a remote host and `[NSProcessInfo hostName]` get's the local host's name, so there is major difference there.  Can you reasonably expect an iPhone to have an accurate host name anyway?

Comment: @Droppy what? gethostbyname() is used to get the local hostname... It can not be used to look up the hostname of a remote machine

Comment: You're far more likely to use `gethostname()`, not `gethostbyname()`.

Comment: "`NSProcessInfo` is a Foundation class that lets you examine lots of information about your running context.." and "`The hostName` is the Bonjour name of the device, which is based on the name the user gave to the device" ... from here https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/we-want-information-information/

Comment: issues with `NSProcessInfo` here also http://stackoverflow.com/a/16902907/1702413

Comment: er, yes. I was confusing the two. I mean `gethostname()` not `gethostbyname()` @Droppy.